# Simple VBS script requires .NET 3.5 when .NET 4.0 is available

Tags: .net, vbscript, wsh

I'm trying to hash a string using the following code, kindly provided by the angry technician: 
http://angrytechnician.wordpress.com/2011/02/11/replicating-phps-sha1-in-vbscript/

Unfortunately, I don't know enough about VBS to understand why any use of **UTF8Encoding** or **SHA1CryptoServiceProvider** results in machines prompting to install .NET 3.5 - even if the machine has .NET 4 or 4.5 pre-installed (like on windows 8), when both of these classes seem to exist in .NET 4 and 4.5

Can anyone please explain, and offer an explination of how to make it use the classes that are available. Or offer an alternative! Thanks!

```
Function GenerateHash(strValue)
  Dim asc, enc, bytes, instr, outstr, pos

  'Borrow some objects from .NET (supported from 1.1 onwards)
  Set asc = CreateObject("System.Text.UTF8Encoding")
  Set enc = CreateObject("System.Security.Cryptography.SHA1CryptoServiceProvider")

  'Convert the string to a byte array and hash it
  bytes = asc.GetBytes_4(strValue)
  bytes = enc.ComputeHash_2((bytes))

  outstr = ""
  'Convert the byte array to a hex string
  For pos = 1 To Lenb(bytes)
   outstr = outstr & LCase(Right("0" & Hex(Ascb(Midb(bytes, pos, 1))), 2))
  Next

  GenerateHash = outstr
End Function
```

Comment: Microsoft takes backwards compatibility *very* seriously.  Especially for these kind of scriptlets, code written by a programmer that left long ago without anybody remembering what problem it solved.  So the registry entry for these ProgIDs still point to v2.0.0.0.  Finding somebody that knows what the message means is not difficult, it takes but a handful of minutes.

Comment: Thanks Hans, is there a way of specifically calling the class (of the same name) made available in .NET 4.0 that I am missing then?

Comment: No, not as long as you use a scripting language.

Answer (score 2):

This script computes the MD5 hash of a string.

**MD5 Hash Generator.vbs**

```
Option Explicit
Private Const Title = "MD5 Hash Generator"
Private lngTrack
Private arrLongConversion(4)
Private arrSplit64(63)
Private Const OFFSET_4 = 4294967296
Private Const MAXINT_4 = 2147483647
Private Const S11 = 7
Private Const S12 = 12
Private Const S13 = 17
Private Const S14 = 22
Private Const S21 = 5
Private Const S22 = 9
Private Const S23 = 14
Private Const S24 = 20
Private Const S31 = 4
Private Const S32 = 11
Private Const S33 = 16
Private Const S34 = 23
Private Const S41 = 6
Private Const S42 = 10
Private Const S43 = 15
Private Const S44 = 21
Dim MyString
MyString = InputBox("Computes the MD5 hash of a string" & vbcr & vbcr &_
"Just type a string to get its MD5 Hash !",Title,"Hackoo")
MsgBox "The MD5 hash of " & DblQuote(MyString) & vbcr & vbcr & MD5Hash(MyString),Vbinformation,Title
' --------------------------------------
Function MD5Hash(str)
        MD5Hash = CalculateMD5(str)
End Function
' --------------------------------------
Function DblQuote(Str)
    DblQuote = Chr(34) & Str & Chr(34)
End Function
' --------------------------------------
Function ReadTextFile(FileName,CharSet)
    Const adTypeText = 2
    Dim BinaryStream : Set BinaryStream = CreateObject("ADODB.Stream")
    BinaryStream.Type = adTypeText
    If Len(CharSet) > 0 Then
        BinaryStream.CharSet = CharSet
    End If
    BinaryStream.Open
    BinaryStream.LoadFromFile FileName
    ReadTextFile = BinaryStream.ReadText
End Function
' -----------------------------
Function BinaryToString(Binary)
Dim cl1, cl2, cl3, pl1, pl2, pl3
Dim L
    cl1 = 1
    cl2 = 1
    cl3 = 1
    L = LenB(Binary)
    Do While cl1<=L
        pl3 = pl3 & Chr(AscB(MidB(Binary,cl1,1)))
        cl1 = cl1 + 1
        cl3 = cl3 + 1
        If cl3>300 Then
            pl2 = pl2 & pl3
            pl3 = ""
            cl3 = 1
            cl2 = cl2 + 1
            If cl2>200 Then
                pl1 = pl1 & pl2
                pl2 = ""
                cl2 = 1
            End If
        End If
    Loop
    BinaryToString = pl1 & pl2 & pl3
End Function
' -------------------------------------------------------
Private Function MD5Round(strRound, a, b, C, d, X, S, ac)
    Select Case strRound
        Case "FF"
            a = MD5LongAdd4(a, (b And C) Or (Not (b) And d), X, ac)
            a = MD5Rotate(a, S)
            a = MD5LongAdd(a, b)       
        Case "GG"
            a = MD5LongAdd4(a, (b And d) Or (C And Not (d)), X, ac)
            a = MD5Rotate(a, S)
            a = MD5LongAdd(a, b)            
        Case "HH"
            a = MD5LongAdd4(a, b Xor C Xor d, X, ac)
            a = MD5Rotate(a, S)
            a = MD5LongAdd(a, b)          
        Case "II"
            a = MD5LongAdd4(a, C Xor (b Or Not (d)), X, ac)
            a = MD5Rotate(a, S)
            a = MD5LongAdd(a, b)
    End Select
End Function
' -------------------------------------------
Private Function MD5Rotate(lngValue, lngBits)
    Dim lngSign
    Dim lngI  
    lngBits = (lngBits Mod 32)
    If lngBits = 0 Then MD5Rotate = lngValue: Exit Function
    For lngI = 1 To lngBits
        lngSign = lngValue And &HC0000000
        lngValue = (lngValue And &H3FFFFFFF) * 2
        lngValue = lngValue Or ((lngSign < 0) And 1) Or (CBool(lngSign And &H40000000) And &H80000000)
    Next
    MD5Rotate = lngValue
End Function
' ---------------------
Private Function TRID()
    Dim sngNum, lngnum
    Dim strResult
    sngNum = Rnd(2147483648)
    strResult = CStr(sngNum)
    strResult = Replace(strResult, "0.", "")
    strResult = Replace(strResult, ".", "")
    strResult = Replace(strResult, "E-", "")
    TRID = strResult
End Function

' -------------------------------------------------
Private Function MD564Split(lngLength, bytBuffer())
    Dim lngBytesTotal, lngBytesToAdd
    Dim intLoop, intLoop2, lngTrace
    Dim intInnerLoop, intLoop3
    lngBytesTotal = lngTrack Mod 64
    lngBytesToAdd = 64 - lngBytesTotal
    lngTrack = (lngTrack + lngLength)
    If lngLength >= lngBytesToAdd Then
        For intLoop = 0 To lngBytesToAdd - 1
            arrSplit64(lngBytesTotal + intLoop) = bytBuffer(intLoop)
        Next
        MD5Conversion arrSplit64
        lngTrace = (lngLength) Mod 64
        For intLoop2 = lngBytesToAdd To lngLength - intLoop - lngTrace Step 64
            For intInnerLoop = 0 To 63
                arrSplit64(intInnerLoop) = bytBuffer(intLoop2 + intInnerLoop)
            Next
        MD5Conversion arrSplit64
        Next
        lngBytesTotal = 0
    Else
        intLoop2 = 0
    End If
    For intLoop3 = 0 To lngLength - intLoop2 - 1
        arrSplit64(lngBytesTotal + intLoop3) = bytBuffer(intLoop2 + intLoop3)
    Next
End Function
' ---------------------------------------
Private Function MD5StringArray(strInput)
    Dim intLoop
    Dim bytBuffer()
    ReDim bytBuffer(Len(strInput))   
    For intLoop = 0 To Len(strInput) - 1
        bytBuffer(intLoop) = Asc(Mid(strInput, intLoop + 1, 1))
    Next
    MD5StringArray = bytBuffer
End Function

' ------------------------------------
Private Sub MD5Conversion(bytBuffer())
    Dim X(16), a
    Dim b, C
    Dim d
    a = arrLongConversion(1)
    b = arrLongConversion(2)
    C = arrLongConversion(3)
    d = arrLongConversion(4)
    MD5Decode 64, X, bytBuffer
    MD5Round "FF", a, b, C, d, X(0), S11, -680876936
    MD5Round "FF", d, a, b, C, X(1), S12, -389564586
    MD5Round "FF", C, d, a, b, X(2), S13, 606105819
    MD5Round "FF", b, C, d, a, X(3), S14, -1044525330
    MD5Round "FF", a, b, C, d, X(4), S11, -176418897
    MD5Round "FF", d, a, b, C, X(5), S12, 1200080426
    MD5Round "FF", C, d, a, b, X(6), S13, -1473231341
    MD5Round "FF", b, C, d, a, X(7), S14, -45705983
    MD5Round "FF", a, b, C, d, X(8), S11, 1770035416
    MD5Round "FF", d, a, b, C, X(9), S12, -1958414417
    MD5Round "FF", C, d, a, b, X(10), S13, -42063
    MD5Round "FF", b, C, d, a, X(11), S14, -1990404162
    MD5Round "FF", a, b, C, d, X(12), S11, 1804603682
    MD5Round "FF", d, a, b, C, X(13), S12, -40341101
    MD5Round "FF", C, d, a, b, X(14), S13, -1502002290
    MD5Round "FF", b, C, d, a, X(15), S14, 1236535329

    MD5Round "GG", a, b, C, d, X(1), S21, -165796510
    MD5Round "GG", d, a, b, C, X(6), S22, -1069501632
    MD5Round "GG", C, d, a, b, X(11), S23, 643717713
    MD5Round "GG", b, C, d, a, X(0), S24, -373897302
    MD5Round "GG", a, b, C, d, X(5), S21, -701558691
    MD5Round "GG", d, a, b, C, X(10), S22, 38016083
    MD5Round "GG", C, d, a, b, X(15), S23, -660478335
    MD5Round "GG", b, C, d, a, X(4), S24, -405537848
    MD5Round "GG", a, b, C, d, X(9), S21, 568446438
    MD5Round "GG", d, a, b, C, X(14), S22, -1019803690
    MD5Round "GG", C, d, a, b, X(3), S23, -187363961
    MD5Round "GG", b, C, d, a, X(8), S24, 1163531501
    MD5Round "GG", a, b, C, d, X(13), S21, -1444681467
    MD5Round "GG", d, a, b, C, X(2), S22, -51403784
    MD5Round "GG", C, d, a, b, X(7), S23, 1735328473
    MD5Round "GG", b, C, d, a, X(12), S24, -1926607734

    MD5Round "HH", a, b, C, d, X(5), S31, -378558
    MD5Round "HH", d, a, b, C, X(8), S32, -2022574463
    MD5Round "HH", C, d, a, b, X(11), S33, 1839030562
    MD5Round "HH", b, C, d, a, X(14), S34, -35309556
    MD5Round "HH", a, b, C, d, X(1), S31, -1530992060
    MD5Round "HH", d, a, b, C, X(4), S32, 1272893353
    MD5Round "HH", C, d, a, b, X(7), S33, -155497632
    MD5Round "HH", b, C, d, a, X(10), S34, -1094730640
    MD5Round "HH", a, b, C, d, X(13), S31, 681279174
    MD5Round "HH", d, a, b, C, X(0), S32, -358537222
    MD5Round "HH", C, d, a, b, X(3), S33, -722521979
    MD5Round "HH", b, C, d, a, X(6), S34, 76029189
    MD5Round "HH", a, b, C, d, X(9), S31, -640364487
    MD5Round "HH", d, a, b, C, X(12), S32, -421815835
    MD5Round "HH", C, d, a, b, X(15), S33, 530742520
    MD5Round "HH", b, C, d, a, X(2), S34, -995338651

    MD5Round "II", a, b, C, d, X(0), S41, -198630844
    MD5Round "II", d, a, b, C, X(7), S42, 1126891415
    MD5Round "II", C, d, a, b, X(14), S43, -1416354905
    MD5Round "II", b, C, d, a, X(5), S44, -57434055
    MD5Round "II", a, b, C, d, X(12), S41, 1700485571
    MD5Round "II", d, a, b, C, X(3), S42, -1894986606
    MD5Round "II", C, d, a, b, X(10), S43, -1051523
    MD5Round "II", b, C, d, a, X(1), S44, -2054922799
    MD5Round "II", a, b, C, d, X(8), S41, 1873313359
    MD5Round "II", d, a, b, C, X(15), S42, -30611744
    MD5Round "II", C, d, a, b, X(6), S43, -1560198380
    MD5Round "II", b, C, d, a, X(13), S44, 1309151649
    MD5Round "II", a, b, C, d, X(4), S41, -145523070
    MD5Round "II", d, a, b, C, X(11), S42, -1120210379
    MD5Round "II", C, d, a, b, X(2), S43, 718787259
    MD5Round "II", b, C, d, a, X(9), S44, -343485551

    arrLongConversion(1) = MD5LongAdd(arrLongConversion(1), a)
    arrLongConversion(2) = MD5LongAdd(arrLongConversion(2), b)
    arrLongConversion(3) = MD5LongAdd(arrLongConversion(3), C)
    arrLongConversion(4) = MD5LongAdd(arrLongConversion(4), d)
End Sub

' -------------------------------------------
Private Function MD5LongAdd(lngVal1, lngVal2)
    Dim lngHighWord
    Dim lngLowWord
    Dim lngOverflow
    lngLowWord = (lngVal1 And &HFFFF&) + (lngVal2 And &HFFFF&)
    lngOverflow = lngLowWord \ 65536
    lngHighWord = (((lngVal1 And &HFFFF0000) \ 65536) + ((lngVal2 And &HFFFF0000) \ 65536) + lngOverflow) And &HFFFF&
    MD5LongAdd = MD5LongConversion((lngHighWord * 65536) + (lngLowWord And &HFFFF&))
End Function
' --------------------------------------------------------------
Private Function MD5LongAdd4(lngVal1, lngVal2, lngVal3, lngVal4)
    Dim lngHighWord
    Dim lngLowWord
    Dim lngOverflow
    lngLowWord = (lngVal1 And &HFFFF&) + (lngVal2 And &HFFFF&) + (lngVal3 And &HFFFF&) + (lngVal4 And &HFFFF&)
    lngOverflow = lngLowWord \ 65536
    lngHighWord = (((lngVal1 And &HFFFF0000) \ 65536) + ((lngVal2 And &HFFFF0000) \ 65536) + ((lngVal3 And &HFFFF0000) \ 65536) + ((lngVal4 And &HFFFF0000) \ 65536) + lngOverflow) And &HFFFF&
    MD5LongAdd4 = MD5LongConversion((lngHighWord * 65536) + (lngLowWord And &HFFFF&))
End Function
' -------------------------------------------------------------
Private Sub MD5Decode(intLength, lngOutBuffer(), bytInBuffer())
    Dim intDblIndex
    Dim intByteIndex
    Dim dblSum
    intDblIndex = 0   
    For intByteIndex = 0 To intLength - 1 Step 4
        dblSum = bytInBuffer(intByteIndex) + bytInBuffer(intByteIndex + 1) * 256 + bytInBuffer(intByteIndex + 2) * 65536 + bytInBuffer(intByteIndex + 3) * 16777216
        lngOutBuffer(intDblIndex) = MD5LongConversion(dblSum)
        intDblIndex = (intDblIndex + 1)
    Next
End Sub
' ------------------------------------------
Private Function MD5LongConversion(dblValue)
    If dblValue < 0 Or dblValue >= OFFSET_4 Then Error 6
    If dblValue <= MAXINT_4 Then
        MD5LongConversion = dblValue
    Else
        MD5LongConversion = dblValue - OFFSET_4
    End If
End Function
' ---------------------
Private Sub MD5Finish()
    Dim dblBits
    Dim arrPadding(72)
    Dim lngBytesBuffered
    arrPadding(0) = &H80
    dblBits = lngTrack * 8
    lngBytesBuffered = lngTrack Mod 64   
    If lngBytesBuffered <= 56 Then
        MD564Split (56 - lngBytesBuffered), arrPadding
    Else
        MD564Split (120 - lngTrack), arrPadding
    End If
    arrPadding(0) = MD5LongConversion(dblBits) And &HFF&
    arrPadding(1) = MD5LongConversion(dblBits) \ 256 And &HFF&
    arrPadding(2) = MD5LongConversion(dblBits) \ 65536 And &HFF&
    arrPadding(3) = MD5LongConversion(dblBits) \ 16777216 And &HFF&
    arrPadding(4) = 0
    arrPadding(5) = 0
    arrPadding(6) = 0
    arrPadding(7) = 0
    MD564Split 8, arrPadding
End Sub
' --------------------------------------
Private Function MD5StringChange(lngnum)
    Dim bytA
    Dim bytB
    Dim bytC
    Dim bytD
    bytA = lngnum And &HFF&
    If bytA < 16 Then
        MD5StringChange = "0" & Hex(bytA)
    Else
        MD5StringChange = Hex(bytA)
    End If
    bytB = (lngnum And &HFF00&) \ 256
    If bytB < 16 Then
        MD5StringChange = MD5StringChange & "0" & Hex(bytB)
    Else
        MD5StringChange = MD5StringChange & Hex(bytB)
    End If
    bytC = (lngnum And &HFF0000) \ 65536
    If bytC < 16 Then
        MD5StringChange = MD5StringChange & "0" & Hex(bytC)
    Else
        MD5StringChange = MD5StringChange & Hex(bytC)
    End If
    If lngnum < 0 Then
        bytD = ((lngnum And &H7F000000) \ 16777216) Or &H80&
    Else
        bytD = (lngnum And &HFF000000) \ 16777216
    End If
    If bytD < 16 Then
        MD5StringChange = MD5StringChange & "0" & Hex(bytD)
    Else
        MD5StringChange = MD5StringChange & Hex(bytD)
    End If
End Function
' -------------------------
Private Function MD5Value()
    MD5Value = LCase(MD5StringChange(arrLongConversion(1)) & MD5StringChange(arrLongConversion(2)) & MD5StringChange(arrLongConversion(3)) & MD5StringChange(arrLongConversion(4)))
End Function
' ---------------------------------------------------
Public Function CalculateMD5(strMessage)
    Dim bytBuffer
    bytBuffer = MD5StringArray(strMessage)
    MD5Start
        MD564Split Len(strMessage), bytBuffer
    MD5Finish
    CalculateMD5 = MD5Value
End Function
' --------------------
Private Sub MD5Start()
    lngTrack = 0
    arrLongConversion(1) = MD5LongConversion(1732584193)
    arrLongConversion(2) = MD5LongConversion(4023233417)
    arrLongConversion(3) = MD5LongConversion(2562383102)
    arrLongConversion(4) = MD5LongConversion(271733878)
End Sub
```

This script computes the secure hash algorithm **(SHA-1)** of a string.

**SHA-1 Hash Generator.vbs**

```
Option Explicit
Dim MyString,hash,Title
Title = "SHA-1 Hash Generator"
MyString = InputBox("Computes the secure hash algorithm (SHA-1) of a string" & vbcr & vbcr &_
"Just type a string to get its (SHA-1) Hash !",Title,"Hackoo")
hash = sha1(MyString)
MsgBox "The SHA-1 Hash of " & DblQuote(MyString) & vbcr & vbcr & sha1(MyString),Vbinformation,Title
' ----------------------------------
Function DblQuote(Str)
    DblQuote = Chr(34) & Str & Chr(34)
End Function
'----------------------------------
function tohex(value)
  value = clng(value)
  tohex = lcase(hex(value))
  do while len(tohex) < 8
    tohex = "0" & tohex
  loop
end function
'----------------------------------
function tobin(value)
  dim hexstr,i
  hexstr = tohex(value)
  tobin = ""
  for i = 1 to len(hexstr)
    select case mid(hexstr, i, 1)
      case "f", "F"
        tobin = tobin & "1111"
      case "e", "E"
        tobin = tobin & "1110"
      case "d", "D"
        tobin = tobin & "1101"
      case "c", "C"
        tobin = tobin & "1100"
      case "b", "B"
        tobin = tobin & "1011"
      case "a", "A"
        tobin = tobin & "1010"
      case "9"
        tobin = tobin & "1001"
      case "8"
        tobin = tobin & "1000"
      case "7"
        tobin = tobin & "0111"
      case "6"
        tobin = tobin & "0110"
      case "5"
        tobin = tobin & "0101"
      case "4"
        tobin = tobin & "0100"
      case "3"
        tobin = tobin & "0011"
      case "2"
        tobin = tobin & "0010"
      case "1"
        tobin = tobin & "0001"
      case else
        tobin = tobin & "0000"
    end select
  next
end function
'----------------------------------
function bin2dec(binstr)
  dim flip,i
  flip = false
  bin2dec = clng(0)
  if left(binstr,1) = "0" then
    for i = 1 to len(binstr)
      if mid(binstr,33-i,1)="1" then
        bin2dec = bin2dec + (2^(i-1))
      end if
    next
  else
    for i = 1 to len(binstr)
      if flip then
        if mid(binstr,33-i,1)="0" then
          bin2dec = bin2dec - (2^(i-1))
        end if
      else
        if mid(binstr,33-i,1)="1" then
          bin2dec = bin2dec - (2^(i-1))
          flip = true
        end if
      end if
    next
  end if
end function  
'----------------------------------
function rshift(value,count)
  dim binstr
  if count >= 32 then
    binstr = ""
  elseif count > 0 then
    binstr = left(tobin(value), 32-count)
  else
    binstr = tobin(value)
  end if
  do while len(binstr) < 32
    binstr = "0" + binstr
  loop
  rshift = bin2dec(binstr)  
end function
'----------------------------------
function lshift(value,count)
  dim binstr
  if count >= 32 then
    binstr = ""
  elseif count > 0 then
    binstr = right(tobin(value), 32-count)
  else
    binstr = tobin(value)
  end if
  do while len(binstr) < 32
    binstr = binstr + "0"
  loop
  lshift = bin2dec(binstr)
end function
'----------------------------------
function rol(value,count)
  rol = lshift(value,count) or rshift(value,32-count)
end function
'----------------------------------
function add32(a,b)
  dim bina, binb, total, result, carry ,i
  bina = tobin(a)
  binb = tobin(b)
  result = ""
  carry = "0"
  for i = 1 to 32
    total = 0
    if mid(bina,33-i,1)="1" then total = total + 1
    if mid(binb,33-i,1)="1" then total = total + 1
    if carry="1" then total = total + 1
    select case total
      case 3
        carry = "1"
        result = "1" + result
      case 2
        carry = "1"
        result = "0" + result
      case 1
        carry = "0"
        result = "1" + result
      case else
        carry = "0"
        result = "0" + result
    end select
  next
  add32 = bin2dec(result)    
end function
'----------------------------------
function f(b,c,d,t)
  if t < 20 then
    f = (b and c) or ((not b) and d)
  elseif t < 40 then
    f = b xor c xor d
  elseif t < 60 then
    f = (b and c) or (b and d) or (c and d)
  else
    f = b xor c xor d
  end if
end function
'----------------------------------
function k(t)
  if t < 20 then
    k = clng(1518500249)
  elseif t < 40 then
    k = clng(1859775393)
  elseif t < 60 then
    k = clng(-1894007588)
  else
    k = clng(-899497514)
  end if
end function
'----------------------------------
function pad(message)
  dim l,n,i
  l = len(message)
  n = (((l+8) \ 64) + 1)*16
  redim m(n-1)
  for i = 0 to n-1
    m(i) = clng(0)
  next
  for i = 0 to l-1
    m(i\4) = m(i\4) or lshift(asc(mid(message,i+1,1)),(24-(i mod 4)*8))
  next
  m(l\4) = m(l\4) or lshift(clng(128),(24-(l mod 4)*8))
  m(n-1) = l*8
  pad = m
end function
'---------------------------------- 
function sha1(message)
  dim h0, h1, h2, h3, h4
  dim a, b, c, d, e, temp
  dim l, n ,m ,block ,t
  dim w(79)

  l = len(message)
  n = (((l+8) \ 64) + 1)*16
  m = pad(message)

  h0 = clng(1732584193)
  h1 = clng(-271733879)
  h2 = clng(-1732584194)
  h3 = clng(271733878)
  h4 = clng(-1009589776)

  for block = 0 to n-1 step 16
    a = h0
    b = h1
    c = h2
    d = h3
    e = h4
    for t = 0 to 79
      if t < 16 then
        w(t) = m(block + t)
      else
        w(t) = rol(w(t-3) xor w(t-8) xor w(t-14) xor w(t-16),1)
      end if
      temp = add32(rol(a,5),add32(f(b,c,d,t),add32(e,add32(w(t),k(t)))))
      e = d
      d = c
      c = rol(b,30)
      b = a
      a = temp
    next
    h0 = add32(h0, a)
    h1 = add32(h1, b)
    h2 = add32(h2, c)
    h3 = add32(h3, d)
    h4 = add32(h4, e)
  next
  sha1 = tohex(h0)+tohex(h1)+tohex(h2)+tohex(h3)+tohex(h4)
end function
'----------------------------------
```

Comment: Thanks, that's very useful and will help me out for now. I'm still as confused as to why it doesn't just use the latest classes!